# Embed XML into Flash file at compile/publish time?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I know how to access external XML file in ActionScript 2, however in this project the requirement is that the SWF file must be self-contained.

The reason I'm keeping the XML is because it's the output of another program, so if I can keep the XML as it is, I avoid manual data input.

I understand that there's the [embed] meta-tag available in AS3, but I'm stuck with AS2 unfortunately.

Is there a way to embed the XML file, or read the data and store as a variable at compile/publish time with ActionScript 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing extensively, I found that my limitation is too much to depend solely on Flash to solve my problems.

Because I'm limited to AS2 and I can't use external XML, it means that...

1. I can't embed the XML (AS3 feature).
2. If I try to paste the entire XML into a textfield on the stage, it surpass the max char limit of 65535.
3. I can't paste the XML straight into code editor (multi-line string literal is AS3 feature).
4. For #3, Even after I escaped all quotes and remove line-breaks, Flash will choke on a variable that long.

So what I did was create a separate HTML page, using jQuery I load the target XML file and clean up all the data the Flash file doesn't make use of, and spit out the result onto a div, properly escaping angled brackets and quotes, this way the result XML data is small enough to fit into a textfield on the stage that I can use as input.

So the work flow becomes:

```
Generate XML -> Open HTML page -> Copy Cleaned XML -> Paste into Textfield in Flash -> Publish
```

It might be another step, but HTML/JavaScript can run anywhere and is pretty braindead simple for my users, so it ended up being a good solution considering my limitations.

Answer (score 1):

In AS3 you can hardcode XML (without using the embed syntax):

```
private var myXml:XML = <root_node>
                            <child_1 />
                            <child_2 />
                        </root_node>;
```

I just did a quick [search for AS2](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=215891), it looks like you can do it like this (note the linked article mentions a pit-fall or two):

```
xmlData = new XML();
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;
xmlData.parseXML("<root_node><child_1 /><child_2 /></root_node>;");
```

Comment: Unfortunately as the question states AS2 is a hard requirement. Tried the parseXML route but apparently my XML file is too big, it seems to overload the parseXML function, and I can't even define it as a string variable. Also could not use a textfield as XML input, max char limit is 65535 (2^16-1), I suspect there's a 16 bit limit to all variables.

Comment: Then I thing you should convert that XML into JSON (or pure AS) object and compile it. You will get a performance boost instead of parsing XML on runtime.

Comment: The things is I'm actually creating a workflow of XML->SWF for users who are not necessarily technically skilled. The XML is generated by another program so they don't need to worry about that, but if they had to compile the XML into JSON/AS object I might be asking too much.